# Book about a kid who is forced to kill, and is then teleported to the future by an amulet

Tags: story-identification, books

I read this book when I was in middle school. It was about a kid who is forced to kill an old man, by a man that puts his hands over the boy's hands. I think an amulet teleports the boy, with the knife still in his hands, to a future where he is put in a cell and questioned by a girl. He tells her that he was forced, and is scared, because he is afraid of that man, and says that you can't escape the Devil.

Comment: In roughly which year did you read this book, and when do you think it might've been published?